# TunaFish with multi Organization fabric nw

Tags: github, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I want to do TunaFish example from https://github.com/hyperledger/education
with 2 peers 2 organizations like first-network instead of basic-network..please help me with this

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I want a hyper ledger fabric example like TunaFish which support multi organizations with multi peers

Comment: Use any byfn network. I would have multiorg setup.